# SQL query structuring

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help in structuring the sql query in Oracle db.
I have 4 tables.

TableMain-
rollNo
status

TableA-
rollNo
name
age

TableB-
rollNo
subject

TableC-
rollNo

Now, I need to check if The rollNo of tableA has a value in the rollNo in TableB, and
The new rollNo we obtain from the above step does not yet have any records in the tableC

If it doesn't have a record in tableC, then set value of Status (TableMain) as 'ENROLLED'.
If it has a record in tableC, set value of Status (TableMain) as 'NOT ENROLLED'

[image]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle ... please remove the incompatible database tags

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK i am sorry, i am new to this forum. will keep all these things in mind henceforth. Can you please guide me through the solution or suggest something? :)

Comment: @kiara. Just do not post images; but do not be overly worried, I did the same. To understand why see [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but found an efficient solution.

```
SELECT ROLL_NO,
    CASE 
    WHEN (ROLL_NO NOT IN (SELECT TABLEC.ROLL_NO FROM TABLEC
    WHERE ROLL_NO IN
    (SELECT TABLEB.ROLL_NO FROM TABLEB) ))
    THEN 'ENROLLED'
    ELSE 'NOT ENROLLED'
    END STATUS 
FROM TABLEA
```

Answer (score 1):

What a mess.  I think I would go for `union all` and `group by`.  Then you can use aggregation to implement the rules:

```
select rollno,
       (case when sum(in_a) > 0 and sum(in_b) > 0 sum(in_c) = 0
             then 'Enrolled'
             else 'Not Enrolled'
        end) as status
from ((select a.rollno, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b, 0 as in_c
       from tablea a
      ) union all
      (select b.rollno, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b, 0 as in_c
       from tableb b
      ) union all
      (select c.rollno, 0 as in_a, 0 as in_b, 1 as in_c
       from tablec c
      )
     ) abc
group by rollno;
```

Answer (score 0):

a query like below should give you the result. change the case when expression as per your need.

```
select
  ta.rollno, ta.name, tb.rollno, tb.subject, tc.rollno,
  case 
    when tb.rollno is not null and tc.rollno is null then 'ENROLLED'
    when tb.rollno is not null and tc.rollno is not null then 'NOT ENROLLED'
    else 'NOT ENROLLED'
  end as status
from
  tablea ta
  left join tableb tb on ta.rollno = tb.rollno
  left join tablec tc on tb.rollno = tc.rollno
order by
  ta.rollno asc
```

live sql link : (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/lqtkzv25wydzhqq663tk4fhkf)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you could go for if you already have a table created and you wish to perform only insertions. Also @praveen solution's is also very nice,you could add a merge statement and use the subquery as your source query.

```
insert first 
when rollno IN (select rollno from tableb) and rollno NOT IN(select rollno from tablec) then
    into mainTable values(rollno,'Enrolled')
when rollno IN (select rollno from tableb) and rollno IN (select rollno from tablec) then
    into mainTable values(rollno,'Not Enrolled')
else 
    into mainTable values(rollno,'Not Enrolled')
select rollno from tablea; 
insert first
when rollno NOT IN (select roll_no from maintable) and rollno not in (select rollno from tablec) then 
    into maintable values(rollno,'Enrolled')
when rollno not IN (select roll_no from maintable) and rollno IN (select rollno from tablec) then
    into mainTable values(rollno,'Not Enrolled')
select rollno from tableb;
```